# Change select command of sqldatasource at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, sqldatasource

HTML

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
   <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id"  />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" />
   </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:database1ConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT * from tblCourse"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code

```
 SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand =
        "SELECT  * from tblCourse where name='"+textbox1.text+"'";
  SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
```

But Gridview does not change based on the new select command, even when I'm using DataBind()

How can we change grid view base on select command of sql data source?

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because of `GridView`'s viewstate.

When postback happens, gridview stores its data from  ViewState. So,  You can either turn off view state for GridView ( a good practice ?? )  OR  you  call `GridView.DataBind()`  in addition to `SqlDataSource.Databind();`

**METHOD 1**: Calling `GridView.DataBind();`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (this.IsPostBack)
     {
        string command = SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand; // added just for debug purpose
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT  * from tblCourse where 
                                        name='"+textbox1.text+"'";
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
        gridview1.DataBind();
      }

  }
```

**METHOD 2**: Turn off View State for GridView ( **Is this a good Practice?** ). When you set this `false`, there is NO need to call `GridView.DataBind()` in your `page_Load`  as seen in above METHOD 1.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridview1" EnableViewState="false" ...  />
```

Now the part comes that should must be taken care of::

Make sure the `<asp:BoundField>` or in general any fields declared and bound to `GridView` markup are also present in your new query else an error will be thrown saying something similar as below:

```
A field or property with the name 'ID' was not found on the selected data source
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string strSql= "SELECT  * from tblCourse where name='abc'";
ViewState["SQL"]=strSql;
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand =strSql;        
SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
```

Now in the Page_Load

```
if(IsPostback)
     SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand=ViewState["SQL"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either edit your BoundField's or change the property `AutoGenerateColumns` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Set autogenerate to true and be sure to remove all the fields in the edit fields wizard. If you change the select command it causes the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following :

```
 SqlDataSource.select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
```

before the line `SqlDataSource.DataBind();`